# Can a weather map be drawn on map plotted using ggmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

```
library(ggmap)

library(ggplot2)
st <- read.csv("C:/Python27/csv/daily.csv") 
st$longitude[1]
st$latitude[1]
arizona <- get_map(location = c(lon = st$longitude[1], lat =st$latitude[1]), zoom = 6)   
#plot the latitude and longitude on the google map.


ggmap(arizona) + coord_fixed(ylim = c(31,37.6),ratio=2/1)+
geom_point(data = st, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), size = 3, shape = 21)
```

This is my code and I get points plotted on google map. I would like to know if I can draw a weather map to show temperature at each plotted point. Below is the csv file I use for the code-

```
Name,latitude,longitude,temperature,survey.point,
Madera 2,37.02,-120.19,140,no,
Five Points,36.34,-120.11,257,no,
Los Banos,37.01,-120.76,97,no,
Shafter/USDA,35.53,-119.28,12,no,
Arvin-Edison,35.21,-118.78,5,no
```

Comment: Use `geom_label` or `geom_text` to label points.

Comment: Thank you. How can I achieve this ? The graph color should vary depending on the temperature. The color fading each time the temperature drops down.

Comment: If that's all the data you have, it's not really enough to use `geom_hex` or `geom_bin2d` or the like. You can map the color parameter of `geom_text` to the temperature, though, which would look like a TV weather map.

Comment: thank you alistaire . Is there an alternative to text?  I refereed to the index of ggplot2 docs but did not find the apt answer.